# Get the message of exception when calling a wcf service from jquery

Tags: jquery, wcf, exception

Im calling a WCF service from jquery ajax. Sometimes the service throw some custom errors and when it does I need to get the message of that error. In the error function of my ajax call I have the following code:

```
            error: function(data) {
              alert("responseText: " + data.responseText);
            }
```

And the responseText when the error is thrown looks something like:

```
responseText: {"ExceptionDetail":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":null,"Message":"Denied",......}}
```

I want to get the "Message" from "ExceptionDetail" but I'm not sure how to do it.

My WCF service looks like this, to test it I just throw an error:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string myFunction(string id)
{
    throw new Exception("Denied");
}
```

How can I get the Message of the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, WCF will **not** return any exception details - that is a wanted feature, by design, in order not to divulge too much information back to a possible attacker.

If you want to enable detailed exception messages, you can do this by enabling a behavior on the server side:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debugBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service name="YourService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="debugBehavior">
             .....
        </service>
    </services>
```

But even now - you need to be aware that WCF should be interoperable, thus a client might not be running on .NET --> therefore you cannot just simply throw back an exception - that's a .NET specific construct.

Your best option is to catch all exceptions on the server (using e.g. the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface), and turning those into SOAP faults - the interoperable equivalent of a .NET exception. If you know that the other end is a .NET client at all times, you can easily convert a .NET exception into a `FaultException<T>` where T is your .NET exception.

When you do this, you can catch an exception on the client by trapping the `FaultException<T>`, and its `.Detail` property should contain the normal .NET exception as you know it (and that contains a `.Message` property with the exception message).

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to do is to set <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" /> in web.config as mention by marc_s like:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  **<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />**
</behavior>
```

In addition to that at jquery level in error part you need to parse error response that contains exception like:

```
 .error(function (response, q, t) {
      var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    });
```

Then using r.Message you can actully show exception text.

Look complete code: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/04/jquery-ajax-handle-exception-thrown-by.html